# How can I order SQL results after they have been requested?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

Is there a way to order my SQL results after they have been delivered? So far I have two values. My code currently returns the results and can sort by the dates `ORDER BY date ASC`
The database entries of interest are.

```
| date       | weeks |
| 2020-07-01 | 2     | 
| 2020-07-01 | 3     |
| 2020-07-01 | 5     |
```

Weeks represents how many weeks away the next date is. so 2020-07-21, 2020-08-03, and so on (I am able to return these values). The `order by` needs to be able to order the dates and take into account the week value from the closest week to the furthest.

I have tried just updating the database with a new field called final_date, although this makes everything cluttery.

When the data is returned, I can find the new date using:

```
$addWeeks = strtotime('+'.$numberOfWeeks.' weeks', strtotime($last));
```

Although, I cannot find a way to order the results by that new value.

Comment: Are you really storing dates in that format and what datatype is date?

Comment: @P.Salmon my date format is actually (2020-07-01). The date is an actual date value in the SQL database

Comment: Always make sure that the example data has the identical format as your real data to reduce confusion and misunderstandings.

Comment: I updated the question to include the correct data format.  @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `7-08-2020` is not the same format as `2020-07-01`. Sorting on those two would give you the records in completely different orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The order by needs to be able to order the dates and take into account the week value from the closest week to the furthest.

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by t.date + interval t.weeks week
```

Note that this assumes that column `date` is of `date` datatype, not string; else, you need to convert it to a date first, using `str_to_date()` for example.